# How to load only new images in recyclerview but not the old images?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using a recycler view in android now the problem i am facing is that whenever i scroll the previous images loads again from the server but as i have loaded them once i dont want to fetch them from the server again and again so can someone please help me out how can i load only images from the server that are newly fetched inside the adapter.

My code i am using picasso library to load images whenever recyclerview binds the data to the recyclerview

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Log.d("mmmm", image_url.get(position));
        Log.d("scroll", "fir aya");
        Picasso.with(context).load("http://192.168.0.15:1337/offers/" + image_url.get(position)).into(holder.imageView);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picasso has automatic caching but u can also configure its cache size using below code

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).memoryCache(
        new LruCache(cacheSize)).build();
        int memClass = ((ActivityManager) mApplicationContext
        .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
        .getLargeMemoryClass();
        int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 4;
```

Answer (score 2):

Picasso has automatic caching, and i think you can't configure it. [UniversalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) give you option to configure the cache settings, maybe you should try it.

Comment: actally i think it doing the caching but only when i am using centercrop with resize otherwise not cahing ?? do u know why it is doing that ??